# Is a question consisting of 4 (only slightly related) questions a good review audit?

Tags: discussion

[Difference between installation of ubuntu software center and command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826014/difference-between-installation-of-ubuntu-software-center-and-command-line) is used as audit for "Low quality posts". 1. and 2. are ok to asked like that. 3. already is a separate question which is tolerable, but I'd add the default ~"It'd be preferrable to split your question" comment. I don't see how 4. has anything to do with the title or 1. to 3. which make up 80 % of the question. I wouldn't upvote the question Without the two comment requesting for clarification being resolved.

I know that the questions are selected by an algorithm, but imo it needs to be adjusted here. I'd go so far to select this as "recommend deletion" (because of low quality) audit.

Comment: I would have failed that audit too

Comment: I see now that it is closed correctly as too broad.

Comment: The four questions could all be related *if changes were made* to refine them. For example: "4. after backup and restore, some commands disappeared, could this be due to GUI vs. CLI installation?". Indeed perhaps the title needed to be changed so something like this which is probably the most important thing to the OP. I know it would be for me.... losing stuff on restore!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this happens. I don't know the details of how the questions are selected but as far as I know, if a question has an accepted answer it is considered 'good' by the algorithm.

While not perfect, this works well enough most of the time. Don't worry about failing it, it happens to all of us and, while annoying, it's no big deal.

Comment: Unless you do it regularly.

Comment: Statistical data issues...